# What is file scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

What is variable declared within file scope in javascript?
Is there anything file scope, considering multiple files are used in an app.

Comment: Do you mean global scope? Module scope? I've never heard of 'file scope'.

Comment: It depends on whether you use modules.

Comment: There is no "file scope". There is global, function, eval or (recently) block.

Comment: @SLaks, we are using es6 import statements in the app. Can there be any thing linked to it? If I can get any link to read on to clear this confusion that will be very helpful.

Comment: @AndrewLi I didnt know about module scope, I will read on it. thanks!

Comment: Apparently, there is no "official" concept of _file scope_ - nor of _module scope_, but I like the idea that such a home made concept conveys (the same variable name used in _two different and completely unrelated_ global scopes - presumably in two different files having no exports or imports obviously have different scopes). Two good references: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-scope-and-scope-chain-in-javascript-f6637978cf53 and https://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ES6 modules form their own file scope (as if the entire contents of the file were wrapped in a function).

Variables declared in a module are completely inaccessible from outside that module (unless they're `export`ed).

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, there are only 3 types of scope:

1. Global Scope (i.e. every variable/function defined outside functions in a file or multiple files)
2. Functional Scope (i.e. every variable/function defined within the function)
3. Closure Scope (i.e. code block/function having access to its surrounding lexical scope)

Comment: Since your "Closure scope" is a combination of function and block, and you have function as #2, #3 should be "block". Closures are formed by scopes having access to outer scopes, so are an artefact of an ECMAScript [*Lexical Environments*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-lexical-environments) rather than a "scope" of their own. ;-)

Comment: Also Javascript now has block-level scope, when you use `const` or `let`.